# What does the first arrow in an exact sequence represent?

Tags: definition, exact-sequence

An exact sequence is written $0 \rightarrow X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow 0$, but how is the $\rightarrow$ from $0$ to $X$ defined? $0$ has exactly one element, how can there exist a map to $X$, seeing as $\rightarrow$ is a mapping. Does this imply that $X$ contains a single element as well?

Comment: Are these modules? If so, the zero element in $0$ maps to the zero element in $X$. This doesn't mean that $X$ has one element! But exactness implies that the map from $X \to Y$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: @KennyWong Ah, that makes sense. I thought it had to be a surjection for some reason...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $X$ is abelian there is only one homomorphism from 0 to X because homomorphisms in groups preserves the identity.  It doesn't mean that $X$ is a group with one element at all it just means that the map to $X$ is in most cases not on to. It is only on to if X is the  trivial group.

Answer (score 1):

The arrow $0 \rightarrow X$ is a homomorphism from the group with one element $0$ (the set $\{0\}$ with the obvios product) to the group $X$ (not necessarily an abelian group, although "Zero group" or $0$ is additive notation, mostly used for abelian groups and $1,e,\{e\}$ for multiplicative notation and groups in general).

Since the arrow is a homomorphism, it takes the neutral element from $0$ to the neutral element in $X$, but beacuase $0$ has only one element, such homomorphism is unique, but it doesn't mean $|X|=1$.